# Detect multiscale size is 0 always

Tags: c++, opencv, java-native-interface, face-detection

I'm amking simple FaceDetector using native OpenCV in Android. I have c++ native code where I want to do the detection. But the result is always 0. The cascade classifier is well loaded. I don't understand why not detect any face.

Thats my code:

```
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
Face_Alignment face_alignment;
face_cascade.load(fn_haar);

if (face_cascade.empty()) {
    cout << "Error loading face_cascade. Check path" << endl;
    return;
}
else {
    cout << "Face_cascade loaded" << endl;
}


// Find face in image:
cv::Rect roi_face = face_alignment.detect_face(image, face_cascade);

if(roi_face == Rect())
{
    cout << "No face detected" << endl;
    return;
}

Rect Face_Alignment::detect_face(const cv::Mat & image, cv::CascadeClassifier cascade)
{
    const double scale_factor = 1.1;
    const int min_neighbours = 3;
    const int flags = CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT | CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE;
    const Size min_size = Size(48, 48);
    const Size max_size = Size();

    if (cascade.empty() || image.empty()) {
        return Rect();
}

    vector<Rect> faces;
    cascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces, scale_factor, min_neighbours, flags, min_size, max_size);

    if (faces.empty())
         return Rect();

    return faces.front();
}
```

If anyone could help me it would be grateful.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that it always return the empty rectangle `Rect()`? So `faces.empty()` end up being true?

Comment: Have you verified the content of `image`? What is in it?

Comment: The rect is empty if the faces size is 0 I want to understand. The image is good.